# Syntax highlighting for variables and function arguments in python

Tags: vim

Is there a way to highlight variables, function arguments and function calls in python files in vim. I have tried multiple syntax files for python but i guess none of it worked for me.

I guess highlighting variables, and function arguments can make code more readable and clear for me. So is there a way to implement this ? I viewed lot of related questions and most of them focus on highlighting just `self` which isn't really i am asking in this case.

[image]

I am using Neovim 03.2 and also tried with Vim 7.4.

Comment: what version of vim you're using..?

Comment: Just edited the question.

Comment: @FendiD can i ask the reason for which you downvoted the question ?

Comment: i didnt downvote you. .thats not me. .

Comment: @Rohit, does it solved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Semshi](https://github.com/numirias/semshi) with neovim.

With Semshi

[image: With Semshi]

Without Semshi

[image: Without Semshi]

Comment: If this solved your problem, do accept it as an answer.

Comment: I too tried using it and it works well for syntax highlighting but it has some annoyances like highlighting all matches occurrences within the same node..